# Separation of a specific group of dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

hey, how to deal with situation when a half of my dependencies is needed only for integration testing  (runtime deps).

there is like 30-40 of them, if I have them in test scope, I have it on classpath in eclipse -> annoying,  and secondly having 30 deps in pom definition just for integration testing that I run one time a week is very time demanding when developing.

Is it that I need to separate them into a child maven project that I only include when running the tests ? Or into a completely unrelated project? It just doesn't make much sense to do that, because it is not a project per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make a multimodule project, where the parent has the common dependencies and the integration test project depends on the "regular" project and has its additional dependencies.
Or you can use inheritance.
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html